# Why data is passed in form of bundle between fragment to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When Fragment A wants to send data to Fragment B, then Why data is passed over Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the answer. We pass data from one fragment to another fragment in the form of bundle because on configuration changes, bundles are automatically restored by android, If we use any other way like setter, constructor etc. to transfer the data, then it will not be retained.